# What's the difference between pauliOp and SparsePauliOp in Qiskit?

Tags: qiskit

Recently I was building my own PauliOPerator component, but when I looked up the QIskit literature, I wondered what was the difference between PauliOPerator and SparsePauliOPerator, especially in the underlying implementation

I want to know how to implement SparsePauliOPerator. Is there any relevant paper information

Comment: That is a topic best suited for https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/